# Ajax Request Returning Extra Div Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

When returning a partial view to the browser, on the first load the partial view renders as I'v laid it out with no issues but when I hit my submit button and call an ajax request, it returns inside itself.

For example - on first run it renders:

```
<div id="search" class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
```

But after the postback it renders as

```
<div id="search" class="col-md-4">
<div id="search" class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
</div>
```

My View with the Partial View render is:

```
@model SpecCheck.Portals.Web.UI.ViewModels.Search

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

@Html.Action("_GetSearch", "Home");

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i>  Discontinued Machines</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>All Tiers</option>
                <option>Tier 2 / Tier 3</option>
                <option>Interim Tier 4 / Tier 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> Search by Category
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>Select a product category</option>
                <option>Construction</option>
                <option>Technologies</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Latest Model Data</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SpecCheck.Portals.Web.UI.ViewModels.Search>


<div id="modelSearch" class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search by Model / Manufacturer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_GetSearch", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "modelSearch" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.TextBox("search", null, new {id = "name", @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Please enter a manufacturer or model"})
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button id="search" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                if (Model != null)
                 {
                     <div id="searchResults" class="fade">
                         @foreach (var s in Model)
                         {
                         <div class="result">
                             @switch (s.ResultType)
                             {
                                 case "Man":
                                     <a href="#">@s.Manufacturer</a>
                                     break;
                                 case "Mod":
                                     <a href="#">@s.Manufacturer @s.Model</a>
                                     <img src="~/Images/General/(@s.TierId).png" alt="Tier @s.TierId"/>
                                     break;
                             }
                         </div>
                         }
                     </div>
                 }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my Ajax call:

```
public PartialViewResult _GetSearch(List<Search> model, string search)
        {
            if (search != null)
            {
                var results = SearchModels(search).ToList();
                model = results;
            }

            return PartialView("_Search", model);
        }
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Show your ajax call.

Comment: Added my Ajax call

Comment: You dont have a `<div id="search" class="col-md-4">` - did you mean `<div id="modelSearch" class="col-md-4">`?

Comment: I did yeah - been messing around with differnet bits and must have changed the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a id before the partial view call.
And after the ajax call and append the partial view to that div. Like below
Don't forgot to empty the div before you append.

```
<div id="yourdivid">
 @Html.Action("_GetSearch", "Home");
</div>
```